# Does google Analytics use User Data to feed its ad tracking network?

Tags: google-analytics

As Owner of a Web application, i am collecting user data via google analytics if opted in.

This collected Data should then be stored safely for internal use only. Now a while a go there was a debate over safari blocking google analytics entirely. Later it turned out, that it is only blocking some kind of third party google analytics tracking requests and cross site scripting, as mentioned here https://appleinsider.com/articles/20/06/22/safari-now-blocks-google-analytics-on-sites-new-privacy-report-feature-shows

Now this got me wondering if the data that we collect via analytics might be used by google in some way to feed their google ads tracking network

Answer (score 0):

If you link the Google Ads account to the Google Analytics one, the service terms become those of Google Ads.

You can also uncheck 'Product and Service' option in Google Analytics Account to avoid to share Google Analytics data with Google to improve other Google products and services: https://www.analyticstraps.com/azione-richiesta-nelle-impostazioni-account/